# Same origin iFrame singleton

Tags: javascript, iframe, singleton

I have a webapp that runs as multiple iframes hosted in a single parent window (basically a modified GWT) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit. Rather than each iframe access our backend service separately, I am trying to have them share the data service via using the window.parent global object. I setup this singleton pattern-

```
define(function(){
    var DocumentService = function () {

        //create namespace if not there
        if (!parent.OurApp) {
           parent.OurApp= {};
        }
        //grab the singleton instance and return it if there
        if (parent.OurApp.DocumentService) {

            return parent.OurApp.DocumentService;
        }
        //assign the global
        parent.OurApp.DocumentService= this;

        //start fetch on instantiation
        this.items;
        this.getItems();
        this.startInterval();

    } 
    DocumentService.prototype.getItems = function(){
      //Rest service call here
      //this.items.push(response); some pseudo-code here
    };
    DocumentService.prototype.startInterval = function(){
      var self = this;
      this.intervalId = parent.setInterval(function(){
         console.log("Fetching items @ " +new Date());
         this.getitems();
      },300000);
    };
  //return new instance or singleton instance
  return new DocumentService();
});
```

So this process works on initial load, getItems() loads the data from service, the setInterval starts a loop to run getItems. I can watch the items array and see the changes and additions.

So now this is where it gets tricky. If you individually reload the frame via right click "reload frame", but not the parent window the parent instantiation of the service continues to run, however when the iFrame accesses the "parent" instance singleton via getting the new DocumentService(), the threads are no longer in sync or something, as the frame no longer registers the console logs, or changes to the items array.  Any reasoning into why this happens? Is my singleton pattern flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to completely resolve this, but I went another route. In the future, I will use the built in cross-frame communication mechanisms like postMessage, etc.